# How to get same data each time socket event is called

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm new at web sockets (also in socket.io). I write a simple app for experiment purposes. And, I don't understand why my event is not triggering on each click of button.

My backend in nodejs

```
io.on("connect", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);

    const data = {
        name: "pikachu",
    };

    socket.emit("receive_message", data);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("user disconnected");
    });
});
```

and frontend in reactjs

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      console.log(data, "zulu");
    });
  }, [socket]);

  const getRandomHero = () => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getRandomHero}>Get random hero!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Object `data` I get when every time page refreshes. How can I get this data when each time I click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to `emit` an event from the function `getRandomHero`, then listen for that event on the server and return something. Something like this:

Front-end:

```
const getRandomHero = () => {
    socket.emit('get_hero')
}
```

Back end:

```
io.on("connect", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.on('get_hero', () => {
        socket.emit('receive_message', data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, friend. So, so much.  (+1)